# I don't know where is the problem with this React Native example ,I have tried many things but it still

Tags: reactjs, react-native

the error that I have appear in the picture bellow.

this is my app.js code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Header, renderContent, Button } from 'react-native';
import { render } from 'react-dom';


export default class HelloWorldApp extends Component {

    render() {
        return ( 
            <View style = {{ flex: 1, justifyContent:"center", alignItems: "center" }}>
            <Text>Hello World</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    me: {
        color: 'red',
    },
});
```

**and this is the error I faced :**

[from real device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUNfU.png)

Comment: btw you dont need import { render } from 'react-dom' in this file , add this to ur root file

Comment: i copy pasted your code and it works for me. Maybe you should restart the metro bundler. But as @Coderboi said, you dont need to import the *render*

Comment: I don't konw what happen with this in my computer , I tried many ways but nothing work , I have Node js version 12.9.0 and last react-native version , did you use same of this versions?

Comment: @AzizMobarak did you figured it out ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine. you can try this

```
export default class HelloWorldApp extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return ( 
            <View style = {styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.me}>Hello World</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: 'lightgreen',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    me: {
        color: 'red',
    }
});
```

[Live demo](https://snack.expo.io/@akhtarvahid/demo)